# Is this flowchart right?

Tags: c, flowchart

I've developed a C program that can calculate the value of a sin function using Taylor series expansion.  I've also drawn a flowchart for the program. The source code is given below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int fact(int n)
{
 if(n==0)
  {
    return 1;
  }
 else
    return n*fact(n-1);
}

int main()
{
 int l,i,t=1;
 float deg,rad,val=0;

 printf("Enter degree of sin: ");
 scanf("%f",&deg);

 printf("Enter limit of Taylor series: ");  
 scanf("%d",&l);                            
 rad = (deg*3.142857)/180;                  

 for(i=1;i<=l;i+=2)
  {
   val = val + (t*pow(rad,i)/fact(i));     
   t = t*(-1);                         
  }

 printf("\nValue calculated by program, using Taylor Series:\n");
 printf("Sin(%f) = %f\n",deg,val);
 printf("\nValue calculated using library function:\n");
 printf("Sin(%f) = %f\n",deg,sin(rad));

 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

And here's the flowchart for the program:
[image: Flowchart Page:1]
[image: Flowchart Page: 2]

So is this flowchart right for the program? Are there any mistakes? I am a fresher in programming and don't have a good knowledge in drawing flowcharts.

Comment: `3.142857` is one strange PI, and your `fact` function could overflow an `int` for `n` larger than 7.

Comment: You need neither power nor factorial functions. Each term can be derived from the previous term, with a simple multiply, divide, and sign change.

Comment: I understand. The fact function can overflow for large numbers formed as the factorial value of numbers greater than 13 on my system. Hence I always make sure that the limit of the taylor series does not exede 13.
And what about the PI, should I use 3.141592 instead?

Comment: Your pi is `22/7`.

Comment: If your program is working, you might want to ask for critique over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The risk with using a factorial function is that it very quickly goes out of `int` range. There is no need to have either a power function or a factorial function, because each term of the Taylor series can be derived from the previous term, by using a multiplication and a division.

The multiplier is self-evident, simply the square of the angle.

The divisor is `i * (i - 1)`, the next two terms of the factorial.

You will see I have removed your sign change factor `t`, because to change the sign of the previous term from neg to pos, or pos to neg, you just multiply by `-1`. But I have even removed that by reversing the sign of `(i - 1)` with my use of `(1 - i)`.

The first term of the series is simply `rad` so I start with that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i;                                       // don't use `l` for a variable name 
    float deg, rad, radsq, val, term;

    printf("Enter degree of sin: ");
    if(scanf("%f", &deg) != 1) {
        return 1;                                   // or other error handling
    }

    printf("Enter limit of Taylor series: ");  
    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {                           
        return 1;                                   // or other error handling
    }
    rad = deg * 3.14159265f / 180;                  // proper value for pi
    radsq = rad * rad;

    term = rad;                                     // first term is rad
    val = term;                                     // so is series sum
    for(i = 3; i <= n; i += 2)                      // we've done the first term
    {
        term *= radsq / (i * (1 - i));              // see explanation
        val += term;                                // sum the series
    }

    printf("\nValue calculated by program, using Taylor Series:\n");
    printf("Sin(%f) = %f\n", deg, val);
    printf("\nValue calculated using library function:\n");
    printf("Sin(%f) = %f\n", deg, sin(rad));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No the flow charts in both case are wrong because 
1) the for loop is in the body of main function and not in the body of fact   function.
2) for the fact recursive function the correct flow chat would be here: http://improvec.blogspot.in/2010/12/flow-chart-for-recursive-function-of.html

now,i understand that u know the basic flow chart of for loop connect try again for the main function and connect the two flow charts.