# Why isn't my code accurate when I change the numberOfTerms?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

double pi = 3.141592653589; 
int numberOfTerms = 5; 

int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n > 1)
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    else
        return 1;
}

double DegreesToRadian( double degrees )
    { 
        return degrees * pi / 180;
    } 

void cosine(double cos){
        int x = 0;
        double ans = 1;
        int exponent = 2;
        int isPlus = 0;
        for(x; x < numberOfTerms - 1; x++){
            if(isPlus == 0){
                ans -= (pow(cos, exponent))/factorial(exponent);
                exponent += 2;
                isPlus = 1;
            }else{
                ans += (pow(cos, exponent))/factorial(exponent);
                exponent += 2;
                isPlus = 0;
            }
        }
        printf ("%.12f \t", ans);
    }

void sine(double sin){
        int x = 0;
        double ans = sin;
        int exponent = 3;
        int isPlus = 0;
        for(x; x < numberOfTerms - 1; x++){
            if(isPlus == 0){
                ans -= (pow(sin, exponent))/factorial(exponent);
                exponent += 2;
                isPlus = 1;
            }else{
                ans += (pow(sin, exponent))/factorial(exponent);
                exponent += 2;
                isPlus = 0;
            }
        }
        printf ("%.12f \n", ans);
    }

int main()
{
    double j = -180.00;
    printf(" ");
    printf("\n\n");

        for (j; j <= 180; j += 5){
            printf("%.2f \t", j);
            printf( "%.12f \t", DegreesToRadian(j));
            cosine(DegreesToRadian(j));
            sine(DegreesToRadian(j));
        }

return 0;   
}
```

I'm using Taylor Series to find the sin and cosine of a number but when I change the numberOfTerms to 10 or 15 it becomes inaccurate(waaaaaaaaayy off), what do I need to change to make it accurate? (Yeah my functions are not optimal lel)

I get a [Warning] incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'pow' if that matters.

Comment: Your value for pi is wrong - use M_PI from math.h instead of a home-spun approximation. (You also need to #include <math.h> anyway, for functions such as `pow()`).

Comment: @PaulR I'm required by my school to not use math.h and use the PI approximation. :(

Comment: @PaulR: wouldn't `atan(1)*4` better? And implicit declaration of stuff returning `float` is really bad. `math.h` is missing there.

Comment: @CassiusDC: in that case you should not be using `pow()`. (You don't really need it anyway.)

Comment: ok: newsflash: you're not using `math.h` but you're using `pow` which is in the math library.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Tried whipping up my own exponential function, the results were still way off (same as using predefined pow) when changing the numberOfTerms to 10 or 15

Comment: I tried to answer but deleted it since the answer below seems to pinpoint the problem (but not giving any solution I'm afraid)

Comment: There is no need for either a power function or a factorial function. Please see this [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38265293/4142924)

Comment: Some quantification would be useful - such as the expected and actual result "waaaay off" is not quantifiable and relates toy *your* expectations.  It would be helpful to determine whether this is a coding error or an expected floating-point precision error.  Note that `double` is goof for 15 significant figures decimal, you PI definition has 13; you could eke a couple more digits out there, and your last digit rounding is incorrect (should be ...590 not ---589) suggest 3.14159265358979.

Comment: Floating point uses a finite number of bits to represent an infinite number of real values and is necessarily an approximation. Errors can become large if expressions mix both very large and very small terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume you keep the value of `numberOfTerms` as `10`. Then, in the `cosine` and `sine` functions, in the `for` loop, you are incrementing `exponent` by `2` every time. And, you are using the factorial of `exponent` in the denominator.

If the loop runs `9` times, the value for `exponent` would increase as `2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18`.

We know that `14! = 87178291200`. But a `signed int` (which is used to return the result of the factorial function) can hold a positive value up to `2147483647`. There occurs an overflow.

I suggest you use `double` (or even `unsigned long long`) for the return type and the parameter of the factorial function. But do not try to compute factorials of large numbers as they would not fit in any data type in C.

Also, since you have not defined `pow` function yourself, I think you are missing a `#include<math.h>` at the top.

Another suggestion, define `pi` as a symbolic constant rather than a global variable.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're a lifesaver dude. I totally forgot about integers having such limits.

Answer (score 0):

The implicit declaration of `pow` returns an int, but the actual definition returns double, the code will interpret the double an an int by bit pattern resulting in an *entirely* incorrect value - not just the integer part of the double.