# C program to calculate the sine of x

Tags: c, series, trigonometry

This is what i have done so far. I don't know what is wrong with the code. In theory it should run perfectly well (or I might be wrong), but it just doesn't and it is driving me crazy. I'm a beginner BTW.

Can anyone please point out what is wrong with the code?

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <conio.h>
# include <math.h>

main()
{
   int i , sum = 0 , n;
   float x;
   printf("Please enter the desired values for x and n (n>0): ");
   scanf("%f %d",&x,&n);
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       sum = sum +((pow(-1,i+1)*pow(x,2*i-1))/(factorial(2*i-1)));
   }
   printf("%f",sum);
}

int factorial(int n)
{
   int c;
   int result = 1;

   for( c = 1 ; c <= n ; c++ )
         result = result*c;

   return ( result );
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger. It'll teach you some valuable skills that'll save you lots of time down the line.

Comment: One thing to think about is what's the largest value that can fit in an `int`.

Comment: type of `sum` change to `double` form `int`.

Comment: I know right, noob here, guilty as charged. My professor didn't really explain the data types. I mean I dunno where to use double long and others, but she said i'd be fine without knowing 'em with this particular example. I'm using codeblocks btw.

Comment: Changing int to double worked.

Comment: There is no need for either a power or a factorial function - both of which escalate rapidly. The Taylor series can be summed by modifying a running term, as [this answer shows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38265293/4142924).

Comment: That answer looks a lot better, But i was trying to find what was wrong with this code, I'll try to figure out how that answer works.

Comment: 32-bit integers can only store small factorials, up to 12! (479001600); they can't store 13! (6227020800).  64-bit integers can only store factorials to 20! (2432902008176640000); they can't store 21! (51090942171709440000).  This is likely to be a component of your problem.  Modify your factorial function to calculate and return a `double` value as the factorial.  We can worry about efficiency later.  Also, you should be using a `double` for `sum` in the main function, as already pointed out.  Frankly, you could use `double` for `x` too, as long as you change the `scanf()` format string.

Comment: You can change x, n, sum all to double as @JonathanLeffler already suggested. This will make it less susceptible to overflow. In addition, if you have arbitrary input x, you need to argument reduction. Otherwise the converge will be painfully slow to the point of impossible to get a remotely correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Main issues:

- `sum` type should be `float` or `double`, not `int`;
- `factorial(int n)` must be able to return very big numbers, so its return type should be `double` too.

Possible solution:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>

double factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}
main()
{
    int n;
    double x, sum = 0;
    printf("Please enter the desired values for x and n (n>0): ");
    scanf("%lf %d", &x, &n);
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sum += pow(-1, i) * pow(x, 2 * i + 1) / (factorial(2 * i + 1));
    }
    printf("%f", sum);
}
```

To make your sine calculator bulletproof you should add some lines to check the value of the input `x` and reduce it at least to the domain **[-pi, pi]** before evaluating the series.
Check out my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169675/python-calculate-sine-cosine-with-a-precision-of-up-to-1-million-digits/45170100#45170100) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333694/implement-sine-in-java-without-math-sin-function/46035900#46035900) to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

[@Busy Beaver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46038380/2410359) good answer points out some failings in OP code.

But to dig deeper on how OP could solve this without *Stack Overflow*.

> Can anyone please point out what is wrong with the code?

Rather than seek someone to assist, use your compiler first.  Enable **all** compiler warnings.  A good compiler will complain about things like below.  This is faster feedback than posting on SO.

```
// return type defaults to 'int' 
main()
// this should be as below  (amongst other possibilities)
int main(void)

// implicit declaration of function 'factorial'
sum = sum +((pow(-1,i+1)*pow(x,2*i-1))/(factorial(2*i-1)));
// factorial should be declared/defined before it it used

// conversion to 'int' from 'double' may alter its value
sum = sum +((pow(-1,i+1)*pow(x,2*i-1))/(factorial(2*i-1)));
// This is the hint that `sum` should also be a floating point.

// format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int'
printf("%f",sum);
// sum is type `int`, the matching specifier is "%d"`.
```

---

By fixing these warnings, code "works" without other changes.  Still there are issues of precision, limited range, efficiency  and overflow in the `factorial()` calculation.  Lesson to learn: use your compiler to help with the basic issues.

```
Please enter the desired values for x and n (n>0): 1 5
0.841471
```

---

I now see this is an old post and OP may be have [left the building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_has_left_the_building).