# Calculating cos(x) through Maclaurin series approximation using a factorial function and a cosine one

Tags: c, function

I have an assignment to code a program to calculate cos(x) through the [Maclaurin approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series). However I must use a function for the cos(x) and another one to calculate the exponentials that go on the denominators inside the cos(x) function. I think most of this is right, but I'm probably missing on something and I can't figure out what.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int fat(int);
float cosx(float);
int main()
{
    float x1;
    /* Original code: **x1 = x1 * 3.14159 / 180;** `transforms the value to radians` */
    x1 = x1 * 3.14159 / 180;                     /* transforms the value to radians */
    printf("Insert number:\n");
    scanf("%f", &x1);
    printf("Cosine of %f = %f", x1, cosx(x1));
    return 0;
}

int fat(int y)
{
    int n, fat = 1;
    for(n = 1; n <= y; n++)
    {
        fat = fat * n;
    }
    return fat;
}

float cosx(float x)
{
    int i=1, a = 2, b, c = 1, e;
    float cos;
    while(i < 20)
    {
        b = c * (pow(x,a)) / e;
        cos = 1 - b;
        a += 2;
        e = fat(a);
        c *= -1;
        i++;
    }
    return cos;
}
```

If I input 0 it returns -2147483648.000000, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: `float x1; **x1 = ...`  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: `int fat(int y)` only works for `y <= 12` because `13!` is too big to fit into a 32-bit number.

Comment: @JGroven It probably is a formatting accident for `x1 = x1 * 3.14159 / 180; /* transforms the value to radians */`.

Comment: if @Yunnosch is right, then OP should be aware that the scanf is overwriting the contents of `x1`, which will not be represented as radians unless it's supplied that way by the user.

Comment: After transforming the uninitialised `x1` value to radians, you overwrite it (in case of scuccess) with `scanf()`. So, while I think I know *what* you do in that line, I wonder *why* you do it in that line.

Comment: Checking the return value of functions like `scanf()` (not the resulting value in the scanned-to variable, the return value) is so useful that it borders on absolutely necessary.

Comment: First time through the loop, `e` is not initialised.

Comment: While there is no answer yet, please fix all the thinkgs mentioned in comments and try again. Cleanup your [mcve], please. Make it compile with strict warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall`) but no warnings occuring.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263886/is-this-flowchart-right/38265293#38265293) shows how to use the Taylor similar to MacLaurin series. And please don't `double` unless you have to use `float`.

Answer (score 1):

First error is uninitialized variable `x1`, and right after that you have use:

```
int x1; // <<< uninitiated variable;
**x1 = x1 * 3.14159 / 180;** `transforms the value to radians
```

this will produce random value, you should put

```
int x = 0; // or some other value of your choice
```

In my opinion you should move `x1 = x1 * 3.14159/100;` after `scanf("%d", x1)`.

Than again uninitiated value `e` before use.

```
int i=1, a = 2, b, c = 1, e;
...
b = c * (pow(x,a)) / e;
...
```

than you have in the line `b = c * pow(x,a)` where you go out of range of `int` variable potentially. If `e = 1`, `x = 2` and `a > 31` you are out of range for `b`. Another problem is `pow(x,a)` is rising much faster than `e. thus you get bigger and bigger values thus you are getting another overflow. And here is the code that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

long double fact(int);
long double cosx(double);
long double my_pow (double b, int e);

int main()
{
    double x1 = 45.00;
    printf("Insert number:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &x1);
    x1 = x1 * 3.14159 / 180; // ** `transforms the value to radians`

    printf("Cosine of %f = %.10LF", x1, cosx(x1));
    return 0;
}

long double fact(int y)
{
    int n;
    double fact = 1;
    for(n = 1; n <= y; n++)
    {
        fact *= n;
    }
    return fact;
}

long double cosx(double x)
{
    int a = 2, c = -1;
    long i = 0, lim = 500;
    long double cos = 1;
    long double b = 0, e = 0;
    while(i < lim) {
        e = fact(a);
        b = c * my_pow(x,a);
        cos += b/e;
//      printf ("%le %le %le\n", e, b, cos);
        a += 2;
        c *= -1;
        i++;
    }

    return cos;
}

long double my_pow (double b, int e) {
    long double pow = 1;
    for (;e > 0; --e, pow *= b)
        ;
    return pow;
}
```